# search the contents of a table in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to place a searchbox on my table to filter it according to `eventtitle`.

Any ideas how I can go about this? I've tried two tutorials but it didn't work. I've also tried the filterrific gem but it didnt work either.

So far I just have this loading my table in the controller

```
@newevents = Event.order("id").page(params[:page]).per(50)
```

And this in my view

```
<table class="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Id</th>
        <th>EventName</th>
        <th>Date</th>
        <th>Time</th>
        <th>Link</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <% @newevents.each do |ne| %>
      <% if ne.eventready.blank?%>
      <tr>
        <td><%= ne.id %></td>
        <td><%= ne.eventname %></td>
        <td><%= ne.date %></td>
        <td><%= ne.time %></td>
        <td><%= link_to "Edit Event", edit_event_path(ne.id), class: "btn btn-info" %></td>
      </tr>
      <% end %>
      <% end %>

    </tbody>
  </table>
<%= paginate @newevents %>
```

Comment: Try the `ransack` gem.

Comment: this is all you need to follow: http://railscasts.com/episodes/370-ransack?view=asciicast

Comment: and this : http://railscasts.com/episodes/240-search-sort-paginate-with-ajax